# Getting an error on creating of a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

Hi There im trying to create a project using laravel, but i get this error when doing it.

```
PS X:\projects> composer create-project laravel/laravel MuxlyRadio
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.12)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.12): Extracting archive
Created project in X:\projects\MuxlyRadio
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
PS X:\projects>
```

anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to enable the `fileinfo` extension for PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz when im looking in my php.ini file there is no "extension=php_fileinfo.dll"
line can i manualy add this and so yes does it matter where i put it in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your php.ini and enable PHP's fileinfo extension by uncommenting :

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Depending your os you can find info writing in your index.php or somewhere to learn more

```
phpinfo();
```